# Permission denied while creating directory/file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command in my shell script (increment.sh):

```
TMP_FILE=/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp

hive -e "select * from $HIVE_TMP_TABLE;" > $TMP_FILE
```

I am getting an error on the 2nd line:

```
/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp: Permission denied
Error: Error occured while opening data file
Error: Load Failed, records not inserted.
Load failed (exit code 1)
```

I tried `chmod 750 /tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp` and ran the script again but I am still getting the same error.

I am new to shell scripting and I thought the `dir/file` is created when `TMP_FILE=/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`. However after the test above,  concluded it does not.

I think the `dir/file` is created during this line:

```
hive -e "select * from $HIVE_TMP_TABLE;" > $TMP_FILE
```

How can I change the permissions while the query is populating and creating the file?

Comment: It's complaining that you don't have permission to open `/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`; naturally, a `chmod` on `increment.sh` can't fix that. (Do you understand what `chmod` means?)

Comment: @ruakh hmmm I guess i should change permissiosn within the script ill give that a shot thanks!

Comment: Not the permissions of the script. The permissions of the output file (and possibly of whatever the input data file is).

Comment: @ruakh I tried adding a `chmod 750 /tmp/sbg_clicksteam.tmp` right after `TMP_FILE=/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp` and ran the script again and I am getting the same error. I am really new to shell scripting. I'm not sure if `TMP_FILE=/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp` actually creates the directory and file but after adding the chmod line and trying again it doesn't seem like it does. How can I change the permission of `TMP_FILE`? I think it gets created during the query and `>`

Comment: @Liondancer: The statement `TMP_FILE=/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp` just sets the shell parameter `TMP_FILE` to the value `/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`. It itself doesn't do anything file-related. But after that statement runs, any occurrence of `$TMP_FILE` will essentially be equivalent to `/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`; in particular, `> $TMP_FILE` will expand to `> /tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions:

- What user is running the script?
- Who owns the file `/tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`?

If the user running the script owns the file, then the problem may be with the shell setting itself.

Type `set -o` from the command line, and check the value of `clobber` or `noclobber`. If `noclobber` is set to `on` or `clobber` is set `off`, then you cannot overwrite files via the redirection. You'll need to set or unset `clobber`/`noclobber`.

If your shell has a value for `clobber` (like the Kornshell), you need to do this:

```
$ set -o clobber   # Turns clobber on
```

If your shell has a value for `noclobber` (like BASH), you need to do this:

```
$ set +o noclobber # Turns noclobber off
```

Yes, the `-o/+o` parameters *seem* backwards.

#### Hint:

Instead of using the same file name over and over, try this:

```
TMP_FILE=/tmp/sbg_clickstream.$$.tmp
hive -e "select * from $HIVE_TMP_TABLE;" > $TMP_FILE
```

The `$$` represents the pid, and thus changes all the time. When the system reboots, it should clean out the `/tmp` directory. Otherwise the PID climbs and shouldn't repeat. This way, each run generates a new *temp file*, and you don't have to worry about clobbering or not.

#### Even Better Hint

See if your system has a `mktemp` command. This will generate a unique temporary file name:

```
TMP_FILE=$(mktemp -t sbg_clickstream.XXXXX)
echo "The tempfile is '$TMP_FILE'
hive -e "select * from $HIVE_TMP_TABLE;" > $TMP_FILE
```

This may echo something like this:

```
The tempfile is /tmp/sbg_clickstream.Ds23d
```

`mktemp` is guaranteed to create a valid and unique temporary file name.

Answer (score 0):

chmod/chown is your friend but you need to ensure that the user/group running the shell script has permission to write to the /tmp directory.

What is the output of the following:

```
ls -ld /tmp
whoami
groups
```

Comment: Hmm when I did ls -ld /tmp i get `drwxrwxrwx 769 root root 352256 Mar  3 16:46 /tmp`. After I do a `whoami` and `groups` I dont see my username in `groups`

Comment: Linux groups are a collection of users. i.e the second part of the permissions. The output of ls -ld shows /tmp belongs to root and the group root. You probably won't see your user listed in groups. The output shows that anybody can read, write and execute /tmp so that is not your problem. What is the output of `ls -l /tmp/sbg_clickstream.tmp`

Comment: I cannot execute that command because the script I run is supposed to create that `dir/file`. I am getting permission denied on the line `hive -e "select * from $HIVE_TMP_TABLE;" > $TMP_FILE`. So perhaps I do not have permissions to create directories and files?